# How can i update specific field from specific Objects in a dynamic list?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have a series of objects that i display in list, each fiel has some properties: objectID/key, weight, reps. The values that i pass to my update function are not the one that have been modified on the client but still those that are in my state. how can i pass the value from my client instead ?

```js
export const updateUserData = async (exerciceID, date, weight, reps) => {
    let userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    let ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID + '/exercices/' + exerciceID)
    ref.update({
        'date': date,
        'weight': weight,
        'reps': reps
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log('data: ', data)
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('error: ', error)
    })
}
```

```js
updateData(exerciceID, date, weight, reps) {
        updateUserData(exerciceID, date, weight, reps)
        this.readData()
    }
```

```js
 return (
            <ScrollView>
                {Object.entries(this.state.results).map(([key, value]) => {
                    console.log(key, value)
                    return (
                        <View key={key} style={styles.listContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.row}>
                                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Kg" keyboardType="number-pad">{JSON.stringify(value.weight)}</TextInput>
                                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="reps" keyboardType="number-pad">{JSON.stringify(value.reps)}</TextInput>
                                <Button color='red' styles={styles.button} title="Update" onPress={() => this.updateData(key, value.date, value.weight, value.reps)}></Button>
                                <Button color='red' styles={styles.button} title="delete" onPress={() => this.deleteData(key)}></Button>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )
                })
                }
            </ScrollView>
        )
```

Comment: how do you edit those values?

Comment: through a firebase function that i checked with hard coded that, i'll update the code and add that function as well

Comment: I mean on the client side

Comment: by pressing the update button (3rd item inside the view) to wich i pass the wrong values currently

Comment: i need to recover the value that is on the client side (inside my TextInput) and provied it to updateData(exerciceID, date, weight, reps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your changes in state. like

```
state = {
  kg: '',
  reps: '',
}
```

In your inputs add onChage handler.

```
<TextInput onChangeText={(kg) => this.setState({kg})} style={styles.input} placeholder="Kg" keyboardType="number-pad" />
```

Then in your updateData function, get those values from state and update your data.

```
updateData(exerciceID, date) {

  const { kg, reps } = this.state;

  updateUserData(exerciceID, date, kg, reps)
  this.readData()
}

<View key={key} style={styles.listContainer}>
  <View style={styles.row}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Kg"
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      onChangeText={(kg) => this.setState({kg})}
      defaultValue={JSON.stringify(value.weight)} />
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="reps"
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      onChangeText={(reps) => this.setState({ reps})}
      defaultValue={JSON.stringify(value.reps)} />
    <Button
      color="red"
      styles={styles.button}
      title="Update"
      onPress={() =>
        this.updateData(key, value.date)
      }
    />
    <Button
      color="red"
      styles={styles.button}
      title="delete"
      onPress={() => this.deleteData(key)}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Example Component

```
class Item extends React.Component {

  state = {
    kg: '',
    reps: ''
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

    const { kg, reps } = this.props.item;

    this.setState({
      kg,
      reps,
    })
  }

  updateData = () => {...}

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <TextInput value={this.state.kg} onChangeText={(kg) => this.setState({kg})} ... />
        <TextInput value={this.state.reps} onChangeText={(reps) => this.setState({reps})} ... />
        <Button color="red" styles={styles.button} title="Update" onPress={() =>this.updateData(key, value.date)} />
        <Button .../>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: That was what i was trying to avoid, since i have multiple objects in my list, but thank you.

Comment: that's not a problem, since you are passing a key for each object.

Comment: i'm getting closer, there is still one issue, i can for example edit weight of object1 and reps of Object2, in my state i'll have values of different object mixed up.

Comment: One solution would be to make a component for each object and let that component manage state for each object.

Comment: That's what i'll do, simpler to manage. Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: I've added an example component.